# Extra bar in the first bin of a pyplot histogram

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, histogram

When plotting a histogram, there is an extra bar that shouldn't be there. The bar in the first bin has a non-zero height, even though the frequency as reported by `hist` output is zero.

Here is a minimal example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random

t=np.array([random.random() for _ in range(10000)])
bins=np.linspace(-0.1, 1.1, 101)
plt.hist(t, bins)
plt.show()
```

A bar is produced in the first bin, which can be seen midway between the left edge of this figure and the main bulk of the histogram (difficult to see on the thumbnail, enlarge the image):
[image]

Printing out `print("%2.32f" %plt.hist(t1, bins)[0][1])` gives the value as precisely zero.

Comment: Interesting! I see an extremely subtle 'bar' that seems to consist of just the bar edge with no height and no fill. It is not present if I use `plt.bar` to plot the same histogram (`counts, edges = np.histogram(t, bins); plt.bar(edges[:-1], counts, np.diff(edges))`). Can you confirm this?

Comment: @ali_m Good observation, it actually is just a line, i.e. no fill or height to the bar. `plt.bar` does not seem to produce it, so thank you for that suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a small bug in matplotlib that was first introduced in [this commit](https://github.com/mdboom/matplotlib/commit/af9c4d751b3546b845ebb6ea183208d48ff62229). Basically, the vertices of all of the bin edges are set to 'snap' to the nearest pixel center, with the exception of the first bin. This was done in order to fix another bug, where snapping the first bin edge prevented the histogram bins from aligning properly with corresponding line plots.

[There is an open issue relating to this on the matplotlib GitHub page](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/4212), so it should hopefully be resolved soon.

In the mean time, you could either use `plt.bar` (as I mentioned in the comments), or manually setting snapping on for the first histogram patch:

```
counts, edges, patches = plt.histogram(t, bins)
patches[0].set_snap(True)
```